# how to filtering Gridview data

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, gridview

Gridview contains 100 customer, each page 10 customer, how to filter Alphabatically;

If an user clicks A, then list out all customer names that starts with A

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach #1**

ASPX markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptAlpha" runat="server" OnItemCommand="rptAlpha_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbAlpha" runat="server" 
             CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>'><%#Container.DataItem.ToString() %></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<br />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
</asp:GridView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
     OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
     OnSelecting="ObjectDataSource1_Selecting" SelectMethod="Load" TypeName="Your.TypeName.Here">
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="Filter" Type="Object" />
     </SelectParameters>
 </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

C# code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (IsPostBack)
            return;

        BindAlphaRepeater();
}

private void BindAlphaRepeater()
{
        string[] alphabet = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };

        rptAlpha.DataSource = alphabet;
        rptAlpha.DataBind();
}

protected void rptAlpha_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
        string filterleter = e.CommandArgument as string;

        if (filterleter == null)
            return;

        ViewState["filterletter"] = filterleter;

        GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void ObjectDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
        // This is designed to return null, you might want to change it to a default value
        e.InputParameters["Filter"] = ViewState["filterletter"] as string     
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Response.Write("Paging click");
        GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Explanation:

User a repeater to bind the alphabets and use OnItemCommand of that Repeatet to fetch data and bind the grid view based on selected alphabet.

**Approach #2**

You can have 26 buttons on top of gridview + one button for All on top of the gridview.

For all 26 buttons you can have common method like `buttonAPLHA_Click` and based on `sender.tag` you can filter the data of the gridview.

e.g inside your `buttonAPLHA_Click` you can have.

```
GridView.datasource = GetDataByAplha(Sender.Tag.Tostring());
```

Hope you get what I want to explain.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an SqlDataSource, you can specify a parameter in the SelectCommand, e.g.

```
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Genre] WHERE [Name] LIKE @FirstLetter+'%'"
```

You will have to add the parameter within the , e.g.

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="FirstLetter" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
```

In your code behind, you can set the value of the parameter, e.g.

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["FirstLetter"].DefaultValue = filterletter;
```

Answer (score 0):

The Faster and jQuery Approach is mentioned in [this link](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-filter-gridview-records-using.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%=lblNoRecords.ClientID%>').css('display','none');

    $('.links').click(function(e)
    {
        $('#<%=lblNoRecords.ClientID%>').css('display','none'); 

        var lnkText = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        var iCounter = 0;

        $("#<%=gdRows.ClientID%> tr:has(td)").each(function() {
            var cell = $(this).find("td:eq(1)").text().toLowerCase();
            if(lnkText != 'all')
            {
                if(cell.indexOf(lnkText) != 0)
                {
                    $(this).css('display','none');
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).css('display','');
                    iCounter++;
                }    
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).css('display','');
                iCounter++;
            }
        });

        if(iCounter == 0)
        {
            $('#<%=lblNoRecords.ClientID%>').css('display','');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

use this sample query..

string query = "select from tbl_name where name like '%" + dropdownlist.SelectedValue + "'";

Comment: The letter must come before the % sign, like dropdownlist.SelectedValue + '%', not the other way around.